# Laptop doesn't wake from sleep Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, amd-graphics, wakeup

I have this problem , my laptop doesn't wake up from sleep .
Usually Ubuntu was handling this very well but I did a clean install of 16.04 today(I had windows 10 on it before) and I am stuck with this problem.
The os is updated and all that.
I have a amd graphic card in my laptop if it can help you.

Comment: Does it wake when you press the power button?

Comment: No it doesn't wake up like that also

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my Dell with ATI grapics. I installed the 4.4.8 kernel release and fixed sleep and flaky wifi issues.

To check if you have older kernel:

```
uname -a
```

Steps to install 4.4.8 kernel: http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/

Comment: To be honest, I will go back to 15.10 since the graphics are glitching and consuming too much battery. Youtube causes 100% CPU usage for firefox.